# How to asset two property relationships in an object map in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some objects that are paired with validators like this:

```
const x = { a: "123", b: (c: string) => true }
const y = { a: 1, b: (c: number) => true }
const z = {a: [1,2,3], b: (c: Array<number>) => true}
```

I have them all in an object but the type is pretty weak.

```
interface All {
    [key: string]: {
        a: any, 
        b: (c: any) => boolean
    }
}

const all: All = {x, y, z}
```

I'd like this type definition to asset that `a` is the same type as the argument to `b`. Sort of like this (except it doesnt work):

```
interface All2 {
    [key: string]: {
        <T>(): {
            a: T,
            b: (c: T) => boolean
        }
    }
}

const all2: All2 = {x: () => x, y: () => y, z: () => z}
```

Any ideas how I can create stronger types here?

Comment: your interface should have the generic type. `interface All2<T>` and remove the `<T>(): {}` from inside the `[key: string]`

Comment: Each object has a different T though...